# Upload triples into Fuseki dataset avoiding IRI clashes

Tags: java, jena, fuseki

I have created a dataset using the web GUI of Apache Jena Fuseki and now I would like to programmatically upload some triples into the remote dataset using [RDFConnection](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdfconnection/).

The triples that I would like to upload come from different sources and I want to avoid creating RDF nodes that have IRIs already present in the remote dataset. Is there a way to do that without explicitly querying the remote dataset? Returning a list of all the IRIs is a waste of resources.

For instance, if I have this dataset (in Turtle syntax) in my remote triple store:

```
<iri_1> a foaf:Person
<iri_2> a foaf:Person
...
<iri_n> a foaf:Person
```

and I would like to add a new individual of `foaf:Person` which is not the same of the existing ones, how do I generate an IRI for the new individual without the risk of using one already existing in the remote dataset?

Comment: A concrete example would help, Details matter here. Sounds like either you need a naming scheme that keeps different things apart (include source in the URI) or generate unique URIs by using something like UUIDs, or use blank nodes. Overlapping IRIs in data are good if they mean the same entity - it gets the data connected up.

Comment: @AndyS I have edited my question by including an example. I don't think that blank nodes could be useful in the case I want to add new triples that have the newly added individual as subject later on.

Answer (score 0):

From your example it looks like each subject is named after the number of occurrences of the class. To keep doing this, I would count the number of foaf:Persons there are (trivial and quick sparql query) and just offset new subjects from the count.

If you can't contact the database then I would just generate uuids, which should never clash. The subjects won't be visually appealing, but they certainly won't clash. You should be able to use `UUID` out of `java.util`. [RDFUnit](https://github.com/AKSW/RDFUnit) has an [example](https://github.com/AKSW/RDFUnit/blob/master/rdfunit-commons/src/main/java/org/aksw/rdfunit/utils/JenaUtils.java#L16) of generating unique IRIs using [JennaUUID](https://appdoc.app/artifact/org.apache.jena/jena-core/3.7.0/org/apache/jena/shared/uuid/JenaUUID.html), which should also work for you.